# After $IE.quit(), the internet explorer still exist in Task manager

Tags: powershell

Here is the powershell script:

```
$looping = 10  
timenowhms = (get-date -f HH:mm:ss)  
try {  
$Url = "http://localhost:8080/commandcenter/checking.aspx"  
$IE = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application   
$IE.height = 700  
$IE.width = 750  
$IE.top = 10  
$IE.left = 10  
$IE.visible = $false; # can turn on for testing purpose  
$IE.navigate2($url);  
$IEPID  = [IntPtr]::Zero  
[Win32Api]::GetWindowThreadProcessId( $IE.HWND, [ref] $IEPID );  
# quit IE 1  
$IE.quit();  
} catch { $timenowhms = (get-date -f HH:mm:ss); echo "$td_date $timenowhms       Open website failed"; if ( (get-process -name "iexplore*" | ?{ $_.id -eq $IEPID } | measure ).count -eq 1 ){ stop-process -id $IEPID -force }; exit 1 }  
# confirm page loaded  
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { if ( $looping -eq 0 ){ $timenowhms = (get-date -f HH:mm:ss); echo "$td_date $timenowhms       Timeout, page not show"; if ( (get-process -name "iexplore*" | ?{ $_.id -eq $IEPID } | measure ).count -eq 1 ){ stop-process -id $IEPID -force }; exit 1 } else { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 2500; $looping--; }}  
# quit IE 2  
# $IE.quit();  
exit
```

My case happen when i run $IE.quit() already, but internet explorer still exist in task manager.
 * if i run the quit function at "quit IE 1" there, the internet explorer will close/end (not exits in task manager),
 * but when i run it at "quit IE 2" there, the IE not end (still exist in task manager)
 * if run with $IE.visible = $true, it have no such problem.
 * Enviroment: win2016, PSv5.1

1) May i know what may cause this?
2) May i know after the "confirm page loaded", what possible may cause the IE not close?
3) Or how i can trace for this kind or problem?

I do try run this without "try catch". but same thing happen. I try put $IE = null, but same. cause the $IE.quit() description as to force end of IE, suppose no wonder what is running on the IE. it will end task.

Comment: Sounds like a XY problem, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: what is XY problem?
i try to get info from some page and analaysis.
now that part got a bit issue, and i not really sure how to troubleshoot. a bit doubt on the function.

Comment: I assume you're trying to kill the IE process, did you try looking at PowerShell cmdlet `Stop-Process` ?

Comment: now i am using the stop-process to kill those related IE. actually i want to know why $IE.quit() didnt work.